# How to copy int to u_char*

Tags: c++, c, c++11, networking, packet

I have a `u_char*` dynamic array having binary data of some network packet. I want to change the destination port number in the packet with some integer value. Suppose that the port number offset within the packet is `ofs`, with length of 4 bytes.

I tried the following 2 methods:

```
u_char* packet = new u_char[packet_size]; // Packet still empty

// Read packet from network ...

int new_port = 1234;
```

**Method #1:**

```
std::copy((u_char*)&new_port, (u_char*)&new_port+4, packet+ofs);
```

**Method #2:**

```
std::string new_port_str = std::to_string(new_port);
auto new_port_bytes = new_port_str.c_str();
std::copy(new_port_bytes, new_port_bytes+4, packet+ofs);
```

Both methods give garbage value for port number (but the rest of the packet is OK). Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Consider `memmove`

Comment: Why would you even expect this to work? Do you have any reason to think that your platform just happens to represent integers internally in memory in precisely the same format the network happens uses to send them over the wire as a stream of bytes?

Comment: When you say garbage, what do you mean? And what are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the integer from whatever internal representation your platform happens to use to the format the particular network protocol you're using requires them to be in when sent over the network.

This depends on the particular network protocol you're trying to use -- check its documentation for precisely the format it requires ports to be expressed in. My bet will be it's network byte order. You probably have functions like `htons` to convert shorts to network byte order.

Another problem -- how many bytes is `int` on your platform? How many bytes does the network protocol use to express ports? I'll bet the numbers are 4 and 2 respectively. So that's another issue. (Or maybe it isn't. I don't know for sure how many bytes an `int` is on your platform nor do I know what protocol you're trying to work with, so I have to guess.)

You can't just write code randomly and expect it to work. You have to think about what you're trying to do and understand the requirements.

My recommendation would be to look at the specification for the network protocol you're working with and figure out exactly which bytes in the data have to change and what they have to change to. Then write code to change each byte to the correct value according to the network protocol specification. This will ensure your code works correctly on any platform.

Comment: Method #1 worked when I used `htonl(new_port)`. Thanks :)